# How do I send a POST request with a specific URL on click of button with Node.js and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to use HTML and Vanilla JS with Node.js to send a `POST request` to my `server.js` file by clicking on an HTML button and it'll append a string to my `jokes.txt` file if I use the url of "/jokes".

Here's my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Node.js Joke App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="add-joke">Add Joke</button>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my `client.js`

```
document.getElementById("add-joke").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const data =
        "Why did the chicken cross the road? To get to the other side.";

    const options = {
        hostname: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 3000,
        path: "/jokes",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {},
    };

    const req = request(options, (res) => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

        res.on("data", (d) => {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });
    });

    req.on("error", (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
});
```

Here is my server.js

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const { method, url } = req;
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");

    if (url === "/") {
        fs.readFile("./index.html", null, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.write("File not found");
            } else {
                res.write(data);
            }
            res.end();
        });
    } else if (url === "/jokes" && method === "POST") {
        writeFile("./jokes.txt"), `${req.data}`, { flag: "a" };
    } else {
        res.write("DOES NOT EXIST!");
    }

    res.end();
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at ${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

I'm getting no errors, but my index.html file isn't even showing up at `127.0.0.1:3000`. It's blank white empty, and the console shows no errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My index.html file is in the same folder as my server.js file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `request` function you are using in the browser ? Please have a look at `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
I guess you are messing server side and client side logic.

Comment: @AntonioPantano sorry, what is fetch for? is that necessary?

Comment: if you want to send a request from the client side (browser) to the server you can use `fetch`. Unless you are using some library that I'm not aware of, you don't have access to `req` and `res` on the browser.

Comment: ah ok thanks ill check it out